# How to get acces to elements from another GUi?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

First I have a GUI (gui1), when I press a button, a different GUI (gui2) is created. My question is: How I can get access to elements from gui2, using methods from gui1?

Example: When I press a button from gui1, I want to  `QuesHandText.setText(myVector[0]);` `QuesHandText` is a `JTextField` from gui1 and `myVector[0]` a var from gui2. The result error message: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

When I press Ok from Gui2 , I want to setText for the JTextField on Gui1
http://img72.imageshack.us/img72/2822/36185233.png

```
  //imports
  public class Gui extends JFrame{

  public JButton Simulate, Particular, Start, HandSelection;
  public JTextField QuesHandText, FlopTurnRiverText, RezultatText; 
  public Gui g;

  public Gui()
    {
      QuesHandText = new JTextField(4);
      //instruct
      ClassParticular handler1 = new ClassParticular();
      Particular.addActionListener(handler1);
    }

  public Gui(String t)
    {

      //instruct
      myVector[0]="some_string";
      myVector[1]="some_string2";
    }

  public class ClassParticular implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){


        //instruc

        HandSelection hs = new HandSelection();
        HandSelection.addActionListener(hs);

        StartClass hndlr = new StartClass();
        Start.addActionListener(hndlr);
        add(HandSelection);
        add(Start);

    }
}

   public class HandSelection implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        g = new Gui("Hand selection");
        g.setVisible(true);
        g.setSize(1135,535);
        g.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        g.setResizable(false);


    }
}

   public class StartClass implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        QuesHandText.setText(myVector[0]); // THE PROBLEM IS HERE, I KNOW IT !!

    }
}
```

}

Comment: For pities sake. This question boils down to the [basic OO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) section of the Java Tutorial.  Note that is explained as the 3rd part in the Learning the Java Language trail.  That trail happens to be before it gets to GUIs.  So go back to the tutorial, and do the groundwork.

Comment: Did you initialize QuesHandText anywhere? You need to assign a JTextField object to QuesHandText before you can call any methods on QuesHandText. As of now, unless you initialize QuesHandText elsewhere it is just a null reference.

Comment: @VladRadulescu You should probably post the code where you think it is being initialized then. Because in the code posted above, the variable is declared: `public JTextField QuesHandText;` but never initialized. To initiialize it you need to construct an object and assign it to the reference. E.g. `QuesHandText = new JTextField();`

Comment: @Alderath: I`ve initialized in the Gui() constructor, don`t worry

Comment: Before you proceed any farther with swing (And java) learn about [Naming Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html). Also, I think you do not have very long experience with OOP. Learn basics of OOP as Andrew suggested. If you ask me how to know you have learned considerable amount of OOP, I would say, Its when you can solve your `NullPointerException` yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two constructors of `Gui`.

```
public Gui()
```

And

```
public Gui(String t)
```

You have initialized `QuesHandText` in the first one, but not in the second one.

If you use the second one to initialize the `Gui` you are supposed to get a `NullPointerException`.

I think you should do this in constructors:

*[Edited as suggested by Kleopetra]*

```
public Gui(){
   this("");
}

public Gui(String t){
   //instruct (I am not sure what it means)

   quesHandText = new JTextField(4);
   classParticular handler1 = new ClassParticular();
   particular.addActionListener(handler1);

   myVector = new String[2]; // or some other size you need.
   myVector[0]="some_string";
   myVector[1]="some_string2";
}
```

Comment: better, but not quite correct yet: now myVector isn't initialized after new Gui(). Make sure that _all_ init is done always, usually best by chaining constructors from few params --> more params. Here move the code in the parameterless into the one-parameter, then in the former call this(null)

Comment: @kleopatra: You are right. I was not careful enough with initialization of `myVector`. And of course, the constructor chaining you mentioned is usually *what should be done* over the one I did in the code.

Comment: you might consider to correct your answer to keep my upvote :-)

Answer (score 3):

1.your problem is

```
public class Gui extends Jframe{
```

that should be

```
public class Gui extends JFrame{
```

2.another problems are

```
public JButton Simulate, Particular, Start, HandSelection;
public JTextField QuesHandText, FlopTurnRiverText, RezultatText; 
public Gui g;
```

- remove `JButton` and `JTextField` because they are `JComponents and API` names
- or declare `JButton` and `JTextField` correctly

.

```
public JButton myButton, ...
public JTextField myTextField, ...
```

3.don't extends `JFrame` create that as local variable

4.don't re_create a new GUI from `ActionPerformed` use `CardLayout`